# MEAN.js - How to redirect after Push function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to MEAN.js and im trying to figure out how to redirect a user after posting a comment to an article.

The function called is addComment and adds the comment fine after pressing submit. What i need to know is how to redirect similar to the way it redirects after posting an article.

**addComment() Pushing to a nested Array**

```
$scope.addComment = function () {

        var article = $scope.article;

        $scope.article.comment.push({details: this.details, created: Date.now(), user: user._id});
        $scope.update(false);
        this.details = '';
        console.log(article._id);
        $location.path('articles/' + article._id);
        console.log(article._id);

    };
```

I need to use the $location.path('articles/' + article._id); properly if the push was successful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what happens when you call `$location.path('articles/' + article._id);`? Keep in mind should  send to server first and do redirect in success callback but lets resolve redirect first

Comment: Nothing. Stays on the same screen and input box goes blank. I would guess i need some kind of if statement to say if the push was successful then redirect maybe?

Comment: It most likely doesn't hav an `_id` yest without getting one from server when storing it in db

Comment: even if i try redirect to root with $location.path('articles/'); it does nothing.

Comment: Also if i console.log(article._id); it prints the proper ID i.e 55ccd1768bae1e5c0a122aaa

Comment: Need to show more of controller code. WHat does `update()` do? Where are you putting `$location.path()` etc

Comment: Ive just edited the Original post. That function prints the correct ID to the log before and after the $location.path('articles/' + article._id); Also not sure what you mean by what does update() do? Where should i have that?

Comment: Found a solution $location.reload(); Works in this case but not really the solution to the original question. Only works for me as im redirecting back to same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try injecting `$window` and run a lower level location api with `$window.location.href = 'path';`

also it may matter that you want to keep your data in sync so try `$location.path('/someNewPath').replace();`

also take a look at your `$locationProvider` service settings

> $location service configuration To configure the $location service,
>   retrieve the $locationProvider and set the parameters as follows:
>
> html5Mode(mode): {boolean|Object} true or enabled:true - see HTML5
>   mode false or enabled:false - see Hashbang mode requireBase:true - see
>   Relative links default: enabled:false
>
> hashPrefix(prefix): {string} prefix used for Hashbang URLs (used in
>   Hashbang mode or in legacy browser in Html5 mode) default: ""

More information about the $location service in the Angular docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location